# 2KW - 48V - 240v / 50Hz UPS - Unknown Topology

Tags: power-electronics, repair, ups, topology

I am refurbishing a 2kw ups that a friend gave to me. It had failed and had been left in a shipping container on a site and the PCB had suffered some low level corrosion. The PCB is a 2 layer board, all through hole main power circuit stuff is on one side and the logic/signal circuitry is all SMD on the other side. I have de-soldered nearly every through hole component on the board and have been removing blistered overcoat and corrosion off the tarces/vias/tracks.I have a blown trace from an IGBT emitter back to the gate driver PCB to repair but so far so good and I am nearly ready to re-apply some CW3300G overcoat and get the PCB back to scratch.

[image: UPS PCB]

** - L7 is larger inductor towards the back and L1 is slightly smaller closer inductor.

What had failed -

The Bat-BUS DC/DC converter was all ok. 'Battery +' connects to center tap of a SMPS transformer and each winding end gets grounded by 2 parallel mosfets (70N20). the secondary side of the transformer goes through a bridge rectifier -> filter and then connects to the DC BUS. This bus is a 3 level bus composed of 2x 450V/940uF Nippon Chemis (2x470uF)) in series. The intermediate '0V' stage of this DC Bus is tied to 'BAT -' as is both Input AC grid Neutral and Output AC neutral. So +320V / 0V / -320V is the obvious voltage levels on this Bus.

Bat-BUS DC/DC had no problems apart from corroded components which I have ordered replacements.

[image: DC/DC]

Inverter stage - DC BUS->AC OUT

So this stage was composed of 2 x IGBT'S (infineon K25H1203)in a half-bridge configuration, effectively flipping AC Line Out to either Bus- or Bus+.

The High side IGBT had blown (gate,collector and emitter all shorted together) and the current has blown the trace connecting IGBT emitter to Gate driver PCB.

Replacement IGBT's ordered, trace is no problem to repair and I will check the Gate driver PCBs before re-install.

[image: DC/AC]

So now comes the topology I don't understand. AC grid input neutral is tied straight to the '0V' stage of the DC BULK CAP Bank. The AC Line Input goes to 3 places. 1st is a 'toggle' relay that connects the AC OUT to either the AC IN or the inverter half bridge/low pass filter. Simple enough.

The 2nd path the AC LINE INPUT takes is through a large inductor (L1) 2 power diodes that rectify the AC and supply's power to the DC BUS +320V / -320V.

The 3rd path I do not understand. The AC LINE INPUT goes through a large inductor (L1) through a bridge rectifier and the + and - out of this rectifier get shorted by an IGBT and that's it. It connects nowhere else after this bridge rectifier.

What does this circuit do? What is its purpose? Power factor correction? )I can find no mention of power factor correction in the UPS manuals/data sheets.

Also in the DC/DC converter what is the purpose of the inductors,resistors,capacitors and diode? -(D15,D23,R48,R105,R58,R104,C47,C48,L2,L3,L4,L5)) A type of filter?

[image: AC GRID INPUT]

[image: DC/DC Filter Components]

[image: REC and IGBT]

Thanks.